# Updating a column based on first occurance of a text in another column

Tags: sql-server

I have a requirement to convert a 150 char free form text and map it to one of two texts: Sibling or Spouse in the member_type field in SQL server database.

I came up with the below update statement that does the update:

```
Update my_table
set member_type = CASE
      WHEN (relationship_description like 'brother%' OR
            relationship_description like 'sister%' OR
            relationship_description like  'sibling%' 

      THEN 'Sibling' 

      WHEN ( relationship_description like 'spouse%' OR
             relationship_description like 'husband%' OR
             relationship_description like 'wife%' OR
       ) THEN 'Spouse' 
     ELSE '' END;
```

But there is an additional requirement: If there are multiple key words for the relationship_description, convert using the first key word.

For example:
case 1: relationship_description = "Mark's brother" : contains "brother" in it so will be treated as Sibling.

case2: relationship_description = "Walter is brother of Mark and Greg Howard.  Mark is the husband of Julie":First occurance is brother so will be treated as Sibling.

case3:relationship_description = "John's Wife": contains the keyword wife, so should be treated as Spouse

case 4: relationship_description = "Johns's wife and Peter's sister": contains 2 keywords wife and sister, so should consider wife should be treated as spouse.

I came to know there is a SQL keyword STUFF that might work. Can someone help?. I need to do it via an SQL script and not via Java.

Comment: What version of sql-server are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `pathindex` function:

```
declare @t table(relationship_description varchar(max), member_type varchar(10))
insert into @t values
('Mark''s brother in', null),
('Walter is brother of Mark and Greg Howard. Mark is the husband of Julie', null),
('John''s Wife', null),
('Johns''s wife and Peter''s sister', null)

update t
    set member_type = case when m = 0 
                           then null else 
                                    case when ca.t = 1 
                                         then 'Sibling' 
                                         else 'Spouse' 
                                    end 
                      end
from @t t
cross apply (select top 1 *
             from (values
             (PATINDEX('%brother%', relationship_description), 1), 
             (PATINDEX('%sister%', relationship_description), 1), 
             (PATINDEX('%sibling%', relationship_description), 1), 
             (PATINDEX('%spouse%', relationship_description), 2), 
             (PATINDEX('%husband%', relationship_description), 2), 
             (PATINDEX('%wife%', relationship_description), 2)) t(m, t)
             order by ROW_NUMBER() over(order by case when m = 0 then 1000000 else m end))ca

select * from @t
```

In `cross apply` you are finding out the indexes of first occurrences of key words. Then you just picking the minimal index different from 0(0 means that there is no occurrence, so I mark it with 1000000). In the main case you are just verifying that if there is no occurrence of any word then just select `NULL` else look at occurrence type and select appropriate description.

Output:

```
relationship_description                                                  member_type
Mark's brother                                                            Sibling
Walter is brother of Mark and Greg Howard. Mark is the husband of Julie   Sibling
John's Wife                                                               Spouse
Johns's wife and Peter's sister                                           Spouse
```

Comment: Tried this out and works out great. I am adding a new column to the same table and updating it with the calculated value. Also have a few other relations like Child, Parent etc. Thank you again for this approach

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know which one occurs first you'll need patindex.

I would recommend creating a CTE based on the key of your source table getting the PATINDEX value for each string you're searching for.  SOmething like the following...

```
WITH Relations as
( SELECT 'brother' as searchstring, 'Sibling' as relationship
    UNION
    SELECT 'sister' as searchstring, 'Sibling' as relationship
    UNION
    SELECT 'sibling' as searchstring, 'Sibling' as relationship
    UNION
    SELECT 'spouse' as searchstring, 'Spouse' as relationship
    UNION
    SELECT 'husband' as searchstring, 'Spouse' as relationship
    UNION
    SELECT 'wife' as searchstring, 'Spouse' as relationship
)
,
FoundPat as
( SELECT my.keyfield, r.relationship, 
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY my.keyfield ORDER BY PATINDEX(r.searchstring, my.relationship_description)) as positionrank
    FROM my_table my
    cross apply Relations r
)


Update my_table
set member_type = ISNULL(fp.relationship,'')
from my_table my
left join FoundPat fp on fp.keyfield = my.keyfield and positionrank = 1
```

- I haven't tested the above code, so some syntax may be slightly off